# Why is God unspecific with directions to Abraham?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, abraham, parashat-lech-lecha

> The LORD said to Abram, “Go forth ... to the land *that I will show you*." [Genesis.12.1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.12.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

> And He said, “Take your son... and offer him there as a burnt offering on one of the heights *that I will point out to you*.” [Genesis.22.2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.22.2?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=en&aliyot=0)

There's a pattern of vagueness that stays unresolved in both cases, God doesn't speak with Abraham again and does not show the direction.

So if God speaks again and specifies the destination - why is it omitted from the text, if He doesn't,
how does Abraham know where to go?

Why is this vagueness?